# Why @this cannot work in my laravel-livewire(mapbox)?

Tags: laravel, mapbox, laravel-livewire

I try to get the long and lat data from the class, but this "@this" is not working
[image]

This is the class:
[image]

This is the error:
[image]

I'm new in livewire and Json. Your help is a gold for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You can apply @this on the livewire blade file only
Your Error Path: vpet\resouces\views\customer\location.blade.php (This will definitely give an error)

According to your class right path is: vpet\resouces\views\livewire\map-location.blade.php

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, can i just change the render function to "customer.location"? I have try that but its still not working. And when i use the liveview blade, the mapbox is not display and broke my css

Comment: Actually you are not following the livewire proper structure

Comment: In your location.blade.php you should add a livewire directive @livewire('map-location') like this.

Comment: And your location.blade.php should contain the all structure like this
<html><head>You All CSS and Head</head><body>
@livewire('map-location')
Your JS HERE with @stack('javascript')
</body></html>
To add something in JS you can do in map-location.blade.php like this @push('javascript) --HERE PUT YOUR JS @endpush
This is right way to do that.